# Bash: What is the effect of "#!/bin/sh" in a bash script with curl

Tags: bash, curl

I make a complex and long line command to successful login in a site. If I execute it in Console it work. But if I copy and paste the same line in a bash script it not work.

I tried a lot of thing, but accidentally discovery that if I NOT use the line

```
#!/bin/sh
```

it work! Why this happens in my mac OSX Lion? What this config line do in a bash script?

Comment: The bash manual lists what happens when bash is invoked as `sh`: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Answer (score 4):

A bash script that is run via `/bin/sh` runs in **sh compatibility mode**, which means that many bash-specific features (herestrings, process substitution, etc.) will **not** work.

```
sh-4.2$ cat < <(echo 123)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

If you want to be able to use full bash syntax, use `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang line.

Comment: On Ubuntu, for example, `/bin/sh` does not run bash at all, it runs dash instead.

Answer (score 1):

"#!/bin/sh" is a common idiom to insure that the correct interpreter is used to run the script.  Here, "sh" is the "Bourne Shell".  A good, standard "least common denominator" for shell scripts.

In your case, however, "#!/bin/sh" seems to be the *wrong* interpreter.

Here's a bit more info:

> http://www.unix.com/answers-frequently-asked-questions/7077-what-does-usr-bin-ksh-mean.html
>
> Originally, we only had one shell on unix. When you asked to run a
>   command, the shell would attempt to invoke one of the exec() system
>   calls on it. It the command was an executable, the exec would succeed
>   and the command would run. If the exec() failed, the shell would not
>   give up, instead it would try to interpet the command file as if it
>   were a shell script.
>
> Then unix got more shells and the situation became confused. Most
>   folks would write scripts in one shell and type commands in another.
>   And each shell had differing rules for feeding scripts to an
>   interpreter.
>
> This is when the "#! /" trick was invented. The idea was to let the
>   kernel's exec() system calls succeed with shell scripts. When the
>   kernel tries to exec() a file, it looks at the first 4 bytes which
>   represent an integer called a magic number. This tells the kernel if
>   it should try to run the file or not. So "#! /" was added to magic
>   numbers that the kernel knows and it was extended to actually be able
>   to run shell scripts by itself. But some people could not type "#! /",
>   they kept leaving the space out. So the kernel was exended a bit again
>   to allow "#!/" to work as a special 3 byte magic number.
>
> So `#! /usr/bin/ksh` and
>   `#!/usr/bin/ksh` now mean the same thing. I always use the former since at least some kernels might still exist that don't understand the
>   latter.
>
> And note that the first line is a signal to the kernel, and not to the
>   shell. What happens now is that when shells try to run scripts via
>   exec() they just succeed. And we never stumble on their various
>   fallback schemes.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of the script can be used to select which script interpreter to use.

With

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You are telling the shell to invoke /bin/bash interpreter to execute your script.
Assure that there are not spaces or empty lines before #!/bin/bash or it will not work.